# SwiftUI pop out temporary alert

Tags: swiftui

I tried to do a app that pop out a temporary alert that only appear for 1 or 2 seconds. It’s something like App Store rating. [image]

But I don’t know what this called in swiftui. Can anyone answer me?

Comment: It is just a regular view in ZStack or overlay... try it.

Comment: @Asperi thank you for answering. I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just a view that is shown or hidden conditionally.  Here is a complete example that uses a `ZStack` to place the thank you view over the other view content.  The thank you view is either present or not based upon the `@State` variable `showThankYou`.  `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` is used to remove the view after `3` seconds.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showThankYou = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Stuff in the view")
                Spacer()
                Button("submit") {
                    showThankYou = true
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                        self.showThankYou = false
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("More stuff in the View")
                Spacer()
            }
            if showThankYou {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            Text("Submitted").font(.largeTitle)
                            Text("Thanks for your feedback").font(.body)
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```